# What is the difference in dcm4chee arc light and DCM4CHE?

Tags: dcm4che

I want to about the differences of dcm4Chee arc-light and DCM4CHE. I got a download of [DCM4CHE from here](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che) and [DCM4CHEE Arc Light from here](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light), but I don't know which one is better to use and what are the main differences.

I am new to PACS server and DCM4CHE, so please give me some example of blog from where I can find more material/data to understand differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DCM4CHE is a DICOM toolkit. Use it for some command-line tools or to write your own Java, DICOM applications.

DCM4CHEE is a PACS archive. It is used, primarily, to store images. I suspect this is the one you want if you're looking for a PACS. See their wiki page for more information (https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki).

Comment: Hey cneller, I really appreciate your answer, but that still not able to clear me, let say I can download DCM4CHEE from https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4chee/2.18.3/  and install it and get PACS server functionality, then what will be advantages to install DCM4CHEE from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4chee-arc-light5/.

Comment: Those links are two different versions of DCM4CHEE. The 2.x branch is quite solid, but will no longer be actively developed (it currently relies on JBoss 4.2, which is quite dated - so if security is a concern it may not be the best option). The 5.x branch is the latest version and will continue to be improved and fixed. 5.x will provide PACS server functionality as well.

Comment: Excellent information shared cneller, could you please share links from which I could get installation steps apart from that you have shared (https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki), from this link I couldn't be able to install successfully.

Comment: There is a lot to it - that link has an Installation page which steps you through everything. You could also try the Running on Docker link on that page if you're familiar with that container system. Also feel free to ask questions on their user group if you get stuck in the installation (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dcm4che).